# Sort command - by month not working?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sort

I have an array of timestamps...

```
arr[0]="04-Feb-2021-21-05-48"
arr[1]="18-Jan-2021-12-19-48"
arr[2]="25-Jan-2021-00-24-29"
arr[3]="26-Jan-2021-00-28-33"
arr[4]="04-Feb-2021-21-06-49"
arr[5]="18-Jan-2021-12-19-48"
arr[6]="25-Jan-2021-00-24-29"
arr[7]="26-Jan-2021-00-28-33"
```

I want to sort this array and using the following command it sorts the timestamps into a new array..

```
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -r -t- -k2.1,2.3M <<<"${arr[*]}")); unset IFS
printf "[%s]\n" "${sorted[@]}"
```

I get this output but it is not what I want...

```
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
[04-Feb-2021-21-06-49]
[04-Feb-2021-21-05-48]
```

Instead I want the timestamps to be sorted in descending order.
So how do I get this result?

```
[04-Feb-2021-21-06-49]
[04-Feb-2021-21-05-48]
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
```

I tried these versions of the sort command, none worked for me...

```
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -r -t- -k3.1,3.4 -k2.1,2.3M <<<"${arr[*]}")); unset IFS
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -r -t- -k2.1,2.3M <<<"${arr[*]}")); unset IFS
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -t- -k2.1,2.3M <<<"${arr[*]}")); unset IFS
```

### Update

I updated my question to clarify that I want to sort the timestamps in descending order and not just to sort the array of timestamps by the month field.

Cheers.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -t- -k3,3nr -k2,2Mr -n -r <<<"${arr[*]}"))`

Comment: I like your answer that shows, as per the [sort command man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) that the character position in a field starts at 1 by default and the stop position defaults to the line's end. So a start and end position can be omitted in my case. I didn't think to try `-n` for numerical sort either. This sort command also works for me: `sort -r -t- -k3,3r -k2,2Mr`

Answer (score 8):

To apply the "reverse" only on the given column, specify it *after* the `-k`:

```
sort -t- -k2.1,2.3Mr
#                  ~
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to apply the reverse only on a given column. I want to sort the list of dates in descending order for my given timestamp format. If I follow your advice then 18-Jan comes third in the list instead of 26-Jan. Do I need to specify a -k for each field and the r in each field to achieve a proper descending list of timestamps?

Comment: This command seems to sort my timestamps in descending order... `sort -r -t- -k3.1,3.4r -k2.1,2.3Mr -k1.1,1.2r -k4.1,4.2 -k5.1,5.2 -k6.1,6.2` I don't really understand it but it seems to work. My case is a bit complicated because I don't want each field to independently reverse sort I need the time portions to be related to the date portions but I would prefer not to change my field separators.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy, GNU sort with `--debug` said that "sort: option '-r' only applies to last-resort comparison", so it looks like you may need to explicitly mention reversing for each key field. Though are you sure you need to give the character positions and that `sort -k3,3r -k2,2Mr -k1,1r -k4` doesn't do? (that last one without the end position on purpose.)

Comment: The output of this command is not exactly what OP wants, since the H:M:S are not reversed.

Comment: @Flex `sort -t- -k3,3r -k2,2Mr -k1,1r -k4r` ?

Comment: @UncleBilly I think that does it :)

Answer (score 7):

Use the reverse `-r` in the key you want reversed, but try this to get the output you want. Instead of playing with complicated `sort`'s, let's complicate it by turning the strings into appropiate date format, then sort, then go back to the original format:

```bsh
printf "%s\n" "${sorted[@]}" | \
  awk -F'-' '{ print $1" " tolower($2)" "$3" "$4":"$5":"$6 }' | \ # 04 feb 2021 21:05:48
  xargs -I {} date -d {} +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" | \ # 2021-02-04 21:05:48
  sort -k1r | \
  xargs -I {} date -d {} +"[%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S]"
```

Output:

```
[04-Feb-2021-21-06-49]
[04-Feb-2021-21-05-48]
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
```

Answer (score 5):

Some perl:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" \
| perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S");
    push @dates, [$t, $_];
    END {print for map {$_->[1]} sort {$b->[0] <=> $a->[0]} @dates}
  '
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that specifying the `M` modifier in a keydef resets the `r` modifier for that keydef, so you need to specify `Mr` for it instead.  This isn't very obvious in the manual, so not surprising that you ran into this problem.

```
+ sort -r -t- -k2.1,2.3Mr
[04-Feb-2021-21-06-49]
[04-Feb-2021-21-05-48]
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[26-Jan-2021-00-28-33]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[25-Jan-2021-00-24-29]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
[18-Jan-2021-12-19-48]
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @ilkkachu the start and stop position of each key is the first and end position by default so they can be omitted in my case so `-k3,3r`instead of `-k3.1,3.4r`.

@choroba's solution `sort -t- -k2.1,2.3Mr`was the most helpful to me in solving my problem. Indeed when sorting on a Month field it seems necessary to include the -r within the key... so `sort -t- -k2,2Mr` but not `sort -r -t- -k2,2M`

After I clarified that I needed to sort the timestamps in descending order and not just on the month field @altblue produced I think, the best overall answer:

```
sort -t- -k3,3nr -k2,2Mr -n -r
```

Except I don't think the `-r` is needed in the key for the year `-k3,3nr`. As mentioned by @Toby Speight it seems the `-r` is needed in the key for the month `-k2,2Mr` because specifying the `M` modifier in a keydef resets the `r` modifier for that keydef. Therefore, to sort the timestamps in descending order you need to specify the `-r` "globally" and also `Mr` for the Month keydef.

After considering all the helpful answers and doing some more testing I found it is not necessary in my case to specify a numerical sort and it is indeed enough to sort on the year `-k3,3` and month `-k2,2Mr` only:

```
sort -r -t- -k3,3 -k2,2Mr
```

Comment: Excellent summary of all the bits from the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -t = -k 2.9nr -k 2.5Mr -k 2.2nr -k 2.14,2.21r
```